# need arithmetic problem proof

Tags: arithmetic

if  $a^2+b^2=a^3+b^3=a^4+b^4$

find a and b

Comment: $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: a,b ∈ R i think the teacher didn't give us any lead

Comment: a=b=0 , a=b = 1

Comment: $a=b$ solves it, maybe specify more abnout solutions

Comment: another solution a=0,b=1

Comment: Thus, please, don't use the tag "arithmetic", reserved to integer problem issues.

Answer (score 3):

If $a=0$, it's easy to see that $b=0,1$. If $b=0$, by the same way, we have $a=0,1$.

Now assume $ab\neq0$, let $b=xa$ for some $x\neq0$, then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2(a^2+1)=x^3(a^3+1)=x^4(a^4+1).
\end{eqnarray*}

So we get $(a^2+1)(a^4+1)=(a^3+1)^2$, that is, $a^2(a-1)^2=0$, which implies that $a=0$ or $a=1$. By the assumption, then $a=1$. Then we get $2x^2=2x^3=2x^4$, which implies that $x=1$, that is, $b=1$.

In summary, we have solutions $(a,b)=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$.

Comment: sorry for  my question , but Why you choose the case in which $a$ divides  $b$  ?
Indeed, I am not doubting about the final answer, I am just asking in order  to logicaly find the proof of the final answer. So why not taking other cases ?

Comment: @Nizar -- Zhao was looking for real solutions, so $b=xa$ at that point o the argument is OK. [No such thing as divisibility in reals..] Because there are no other real number solutions, there aren't integer solutions either.

Comment: okay, clear now ! Thanks  @coffeemath

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof but a visualizing aid that cannot fit in a simple "remark". The graphics below displays:

- the cubic curve (c) with equation $a^2+b^2=a^3+b^3$ (in red), with an isolated point: $(0,0)$. Note the invariance by symmetry $(x,y) \rightarrow (y,x)$.
- the quartic curve (q) with equation $a^4+b^4=a^3+b^3$ (in black), with the same isolated point. Note the invariance by different symmetries.

One "sees" the three common points $(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$, to which must be added the isolated point $(0,0)$.

Note: the solution by @Mingfeng Zhao amounts to intersect these curves with a straight line $b=ta$ pivoting through the origin.

[image]